# SDL2 program SIGSEGV on start

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-ttf, sdl-image

I wrote Snake in SDL and now want to port it to Android, which means I had to rewrite parts of it to use SDL2. I replaced the key control and rendering parts and it compiles without any errors. However, when I try to run it it crashes immediately. I ran it with the debugger, but it doesn't give any useful information:

```
(no debugging symbols found) 
Program received signal SIGSEGV,Segmentation fault
In ?? () ()
```

I set a breakpoint on the first line of the code and it doesn't even reach that before crashing. I am also using SDL_image and SDL_ttf.

Source code:
http://www.mediafire.com/?n0zdd061d343w35

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is on the SDL loading, you can not resolve the symbols and get an error.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?